# iptables rules redirect traffic to hidden service

Tags: onion-services, onion-routing

I'm looking to setup iptables rules that redirects traffic (in this case, smtp traffic) to a hidden service on a different server. I've done this before with an OpenVPN connection, but now I want to be able to do so for hidden services.

The issue I'm running into is that iptables doesn't see the MapAddress IP that i set in torrc. What would be the best way of routing incoming traffic to a .onion hidden service?

Answer (score 1):

If you've configured torrc to properly resolve .onion addresses, you may need to first make sure that those requests are being sent to the proper port (often this is port 9040 in a lot of example HowTo's). You may need to first create an IPtables rule to redirect requests to this port.

You can take a look at Tails as an example to has properly configured DNS via iptables. 
https://tails.boum.org/contribute/design/Tor_enforcement/#index1h1